# Facebook Like Button for the Web showing intermittently

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm using the FaceBook like button on our website and sometimes it does not show up at all?

Some pages have multiple like buttons, most of the time they load, other times they do not.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

It's a basic FB Like Button generated at this URL:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: Could you provide the url where you embedded your fb button?

Comment: Sure here it is, you'll notice there are 2 like buttons on the page, one to like the website, the other to like the post.
http://bathroomwarehouse.com.au/node/1893

Comment: What's the issue? I can see both the fb buttons from this link.

Comment: Well it's intermittent, noramlly it works fine, however sometimes the like button under the post does not show.

Comment: Here's another link where a feed is embedded in an FB page, again it's intermittent, and if you refresh the page it displays the like buttons:
https://www.facebook.com/BathroomWarehouse/app_624887450961463